# Objects from cache in PlayFramework seem to be the original objects?

Tags: java, caching, playframework-2.0, ehcache

Another PlayFramework 2.x (2.5 to be specific) related question regarding caching. Play uses EhCache, but I **THINK** this is a Play-question, not an EhCache question - but I might be wrong.

So I fetch objects from the cache. In this example, I am getting menu items from a database and then I am highlighting the current menu item. This is the code:

```
List<Menu> menuitems = cache.getOrElse("menu", () -> getMenuitemsFromDatabase(), DURATION_14_DAYS);
for (Menu menuitem : menuitems) {
    if (menuitem.getUrl().equals(request.uri())) {
        menuitem.setHighlighted(true);
        break;
    }
}
```

Problem is, I always get the same object from the cache. With same object I really mean the same object from memory. I guess it is stored in some hashmap in memory and I am fetching the same entry each time.

This means, when I browse to two websites, then the current and the previous menu item is highlighted. And obviously it gets worse, if I browse to more sites.

What I expect (and need) is a copy of the list of menu items. If I replace EhCache with Redis, I always get copies (which makes sense, since the redis server is another machine).

So, how can I tell Play to fetch only copies of the cached objects. I really do not want to copy all these objects manually. If there is no build in solution to Play, what would be a generic way?
Obviously, all objects in the cache are serializable, so I guess one can copy these objects easily.

Thank you,
schube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what version of ehcache is being used here, so how to fix this may vary... but Ehcache will indeed *not* copy objects if this isn't required. It only gets required if serialization is also required (e.g. your redis usecase). But for as long as the entry is kept on the JVM's heap, you'll get the same object back indeed.

How to best address this? Well, it depends: you can force "copy-on-read/write" semantic at the cache level in ehcache ([2.x](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/configuration.html#copyonread-and-copyonwrite-cache-configuration) / [3.x](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.3/serializers-copiers.html)); but I'd consider other solutions if I were you... you're introducing unrequired latency to cache accesses because of this... But I'm not really sure how you'd best address *in this very specific usecase*.

Anyways, mimic'ing redis (out of VM) copy-on-read/write semantic is probably the easiest, but probably the less performant as well.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. Usually, I do not change the cached objects, but i this specific case I highlight the menu items, so I change the object. I don't know, either I copy the menus and highlight the current item in the copy or I loop through all menu items and set the others to         `menuitem.setHighlighted(false);` But I am worried if someone else access the website then I might get a race condition because both users use the same object and change it... Well, I will test some cases. Thank you!